# vscode for git - git would not continue unless you quit editor

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio Code as git editor for quite a while. At some point recently however, once I'd edit a rebase/commit message inside a new vscode window opened by git, when I click the "close" button of vscode, git wouldn't continue to next step anymore. The window is closed but vscode process is still running - I have to quit it from the dock, for git to continue.

As this would still be working fine on another Mac of mine, I tried fully reinstalling Visual Studio Code (removing all configs), yet after reinstalling the same behavior occurs. I have the very same git config on both Macs:

```
[core]
    editor = code --wait
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

I'm using the latest stable version `1.13.0` and I don't have an already running vscode (although I believe it shouldn't matter) when I start a rebase for example. It just seems that visual studio code gets "minimized" when I close it via the `x` button.

Comment: Is it related to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11918#issuecomment-306399125?

Comment: Or maybe this one? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4142

Comment: @VonC I don't believe so - they seem to be old fixed issues. I updated my question to include that I'm using the latest stable version.

Comment: Just use Cmd+Q instead of the close button ?

Comment: @KeatsPeeks this is what I've been doing lately on that machine, yet I'm interested what could be the reason for the issue.

Comment: Did you updated something recently? Before the issue started to appear?

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue with a fix is at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/438 .  The fix is (but please read the whole thread first):

```
Clone the repo https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go
cd into the repo
Get the branch with the fix roblou/killProcs
npm install
If you don't have the vsce tool, then npm install -g vsce
vsce package to get the vsix file for the extension
code --install-extension Go-0.6.53.vsix to install the extension from the six
now run vs code as you normally would
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this has anything to do with my case. It is about a specific language plugin or process failing to quit.

Comment: It's about a process refusing to quit when the console is closed.  Exactly the same symptoms as yours.  Also happens on Windows, but this is Linux.

Comment: OK, I'll try to see if I might have installed a plugin that causes that.